# Compilation error : No match for overloaded operator

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

here is a part of my code, when i compile it, it says
1: no match for operator =
2: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Matrix' to 'Matrix&'
but if i remove the operator + part it works
where is the problem?! :|

gcc errors:
"no match for 'operator=' in 'z = Matrix::operator+(Matrix&)((* & y))'
candidate is:
atrix& Matrix::operator=(Matrix&)
 no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Matrix' to 'Matrix&' "

```
class Matrix {
  //friend list:
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrix& m);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& in, Matrix& m);

  int** a;    //2D array pointer
  int R, C;   //num of rows and columns
  static int s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
 public:
  Matrix();
  Matrix(const Matrix&);
  ~Matrix();
  static void log();

  Matrix operator+ (Matrix &M){
    if( R == M.R && C == M.C ){
        s4++;
        Matrix temp;
        temp.R = R;
        temp.C = C;         temp.a = new int*[R];
        for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
            temp.a[i] = new int[C];

        for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
                temp.a[i][j] = a[i][j] + M.a[i][j];

        return temp;
    }   
}

  Matrix& operator = (Matrix& M){
s5++;
if(a != NULL)
{
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
        delete [] a[i];
    delete a;
    a = NULL;
    R = 0;
    C = 0;
}
R = M.R;
C = M.C;
a = new int*[R];
for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
    a[i] = new int[C];

for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        a[i][j] = M.a[i][j];    

return *this;
}
```

};

Comment: Please include the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message in your question, and also point out which lines they are about.

Comment: And please show the relevant parts of your `class Matrix` declaration. Also, the compile error is not inside GCC, it is inside your code, so I feel the title is error-prone...

Comment: You _do_ have a problem that is easy to see, and that is that the `operator+` function does not return anything if the `if` statement is false. This may cause problems and undefined behaviors.

Comment: To overload the `+` and the `=` operators correctly make the arguments const references e.g. like so `Matrix operator+ (const Matrix& M){`

Answer (score 2):

```
Matrix operator+ (Matrix &M){
Matrix& operator= (Matrix &M){
```

They both share he same problem - the parameter type should be `const Matrix&` (just like in the copy constructor). Otherwise you cannot pass temporary objects to the operators.